# How to get csv headers list in powershell version2.0

Tags: csv, powershell-2.0

Now in PowerShell version 4.0 my code looks like below and it is working fine.

```
$columns= (Get-Content $csvfile -First 1).Split($csvdelimiter)
```

But some of our production servers use PowerShell version 2.0.I am getting "parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name-First"  because 2.0 does not have this "-First" method.
so how can I convert the above code that supports PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
$columns= (Get-Content $csvfile | Select-Object -First 1).Split($csvdelimiter)
```

Comment: -First not available in PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works on 2.0 , but it does on 5.1

$columns.(Get-Content  $fn -TotalCount 1).Split($csvdelimiter)

Try changing the `-First 1` to `-TotalCount 1` .
`Get-Content -TotalCount 1` gets the first line , just like `Get_Content -First 1` . The `split($csvelimiter)` splits the first line based on the value in $csvdelimiter. The `$columns` assigns the split line to the variable.

Comment: Please, always explain your code, for completeness